# Is there an R.notEquals equivalent in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

In Ramda I can do something like follows (this is just hypothetical code, designed only to illustrate the kind of solution I'm search for)

```
const highest = function(attribute) {
  switch(attribute){
    case 'score':
      return 'John'
  }
}

const hasHighestScore = R.compose(
  R.equals,
  R.toLower,
  highest
)('score')

hasHighestScore('john') // true
```

Is there an equivalent for R.equals which returns the opposite value yet works the same as R.equals?

Such that this hypothetical code would work:

```
const hasNotHighestScore = R.compose(
      R.notEquals,
      R.toLower,
      highest
    )('score')
```

Obviously I could inverse the previous result

```
const doesNotHaveHighestScore = x => !hasHighestScore(x)
```

but I'd like to know if there is something like R.notEquals or perhaps I can create it myself? Thanks.

Comment: Ramda has a `not` function which compliments a predicate. E.g. `const notEqual = value => R.compose(R.not, R.equals(value))`.

Comment: It doesn't work the same way, for example, if I simply at an R.not followed by R.equals, I get the error "First argument to _arity must be a non-negative integer no greater than "

Comment: Figure it out, thanks!

Comment: @Babak You might want to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then

Comment: @4castle: [`not`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#not) actually takes a boolean value and not a function.  [`complement`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#complement) is the equivalent for functions.  So this should work: `notEqual = R.complement(R.equals)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following (I wrote this before reading the comments, to be honest. I don't know why the person didn't just answer):

```
const notHasHighestScore = R.compose(
  R.complement,
  R.equals,
  R.toLower,
  highest
)('score')
```